# Iterate through an array and concatenate another array all the values before next iteration of first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to build a list of Urls. The structure is like this:
http://somedomain.com/game_CATEGORY?page=NUMBER.

I have an array of game categories, ranging from action games category to word games category.

I have an array of numbers, 1 through 20.

I have pieces of the url saved as strings.

I've been trying for a day to combine them in this way:

```
cats = ["action","adventure","arcade","board","card","casino","casual","educational","family","music","puzzle","racing","role_playing","simulation","sports","strategy","trivia","word"],
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
urlString1 = "http://example.com/game_",
urlString2 = "?page=",
madeUrl1 = [],
x = 1, // counter for page numbers
madeUrl2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
    madeUrl1.push(urlString1+cats[i]+urlString2);
};


for (var i = 0; i < madeUrl1.length; i++) {
    madeUrl2.push(madeUrl1[i]+x);
    x++;
};
console.log(madeUrl2);
```

This gets me partially there. But its printing out one number per category. I need each category printout to have ALL 20 numbers added, then move on to the next category.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to nest another `for` loop inside your second one. Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < madeUrl1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        madeUrl2.push(madeUrl1[i]+nums[j]);
    }
};
```

That way you're iterating through the base URLs you prepared in `madeUrl1`, and then for each of those you're iterating through each number you have in the array.

If the numbers are simply sequential from 1 to 20, you don't even need the `nums` array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < madeUrl1.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
        madeUrl2.push(madeUrl1[i]+x);
    }
};
```

And the whole thing could be accomplished with a single nested `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
        madeUrl1.push(urlString1+cats[i]+urlString2+x);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. That's what I tried yesterday but I kept thinking I needed to return a value from the first loop in order to let the second loop get its data. Thanks for showing me the proper way. Wish I could've figure that out on my own!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
cats = ["action","adventure","arcade","board","card","casino","casual","educational","family","music","puzzle","racing","role_playing","simulation","sports","strategy","trivia","word"],
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
urlString1 = "http://example.com/game_",
urlString2 = "?page=",
madeUrl1 = [],
x = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        madeUrl1.push(urlString1+cats[i]+urlString2+nums[j]);
        x++;
    };
};

console.log(madeUrl1);
```

What we did here, is first nesting our loops. E.g., it will first loop through the first array, and when it arrives at it first item, in this case a category, it will run the nested loop 20 times, appending each number to the page. After done, it continues to the second category and so on.

Comment: Damn, nesting was the first thing I tried, but I didn't have it set up properly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help you. If this is a correct answer for you, please use the check icon on top of this answer to mark it as correct, and/or vote it up. Cheers.